# How to get custom post type title, excerpt, thumbnail and permalink by post ID?

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts

I have to generate several "loops" to get the title, excerpt, thumbnail and permalink of a custom post type 'charity' by post ID, because I will have multiple posts (charities) I need to target with a special class (absolute-positioned map pointers).

Can you help me adjust my code so I can get it to work? 
What I have so far doesn't work:

```
<span id="chty_17">
<?php
$args = array('post_type'=> 'charity','post__in' => array(36));
$custom_query = get_posts($args);
foreach ($custom_query as $post) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>
<dt><?php the_title; ?></dt>
<dd>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title; ?></h2>
<p><?php the_excerpt; ?></p>
<p><a class="more" href="<?php echo get_post_permalink();?>">Find out more &raquo;</a></p></dd>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
</span>
```

This code only displays the thumbnail and permalink correctly.

I tried other options like the below, but I need to get the post excerpt (generated), not post content:

```
<?php $post_17 = get_post(17); ?>
<dt><?php echo $post_17->post_title; ?></dt>
<dd>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail('17'); ?>
<h2><?php echo $post_17->post_title; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $post_17->post_content; ?></p>
<p><a class="more" href="<?php echo get_post_permalink('17');?>">Find out more &raquo;</a></p></dd>
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!!

Comment: you are missing `()` in the function calls- `the_title()`, `the_excerpt()`

Comment: Use [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) to get just that with less formatting - must be used in the Loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. There are a couple things you can do differently to get a better result and at the same time retrieve the excerpt.

We're going to use `setup_postdata` to allow us to use functions like `the_title()` and `the_excerpt()`. After you finish retrieving and displaying this content, you always want to get back to where you started, so you call `wp_reset_postdata()` to return to the previous content.

```
<?php
$post_17 = get_post(17);
if ( $post_17 ):
    setup_postdata($post_17);
    ?>
    <span id="chty_17">
        <dt><?php the_title(); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <p><a class="more" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Find out more &raquo;</a></p>
        </dd>
    </span>
    <?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

It's important to note that `the_excerpt()` appends a more link to the end of your excerpt content. Using the above code will output "more" links twice. You can modify this link content using the [get_the_excerpt filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt).